# Read array element and convert into string

Tags: ruby, ruby-c-extension

```
if (RARRAY_LEN(arr) > 0) 
   {
     VALUE str = rb_ary_entry(arr, 0);
     abc = some_method(*str);
   }
```

`rb_ary_entry(arr, 0)` gives me an index value. Then I want to convert that value to a string so I can pass it to the next method. I tried:

```
rb_str_new2(rb_ary_entry(arr, 0));
```

but I get error saying:

```
error: indirection requires pointer operand `('VALUE' (aka 'unsigned long')` `invalid`)`
`ipDict = some_method(*str)`;
```

Comment: `rb_ary_enrty` returns a `VALUE`, which could be a Ruby string. What is the signature of `some_method`, is it expecting a Ruby String (i.e. a `VALUE`) or a C string (i.e. a `char*`)?

Comment: it is expecting a c String

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`StringValueCStr` macro](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_1_5/README.EXT#L117) to convert a Ruby String into a `char*` (the `rb_str_new` functions are for converting in the other direction).

```c
VALUE str = rb_ary_entry(arr, 0); // str is now a Ruby String
char *c_str = StringValueCStr(str);

abc = some_method(c_str);
```